# jquery: how to detect was event called by script or by mousewheel?

Tags: jquery, events

How to detect was event called by script or by mousewheel?

For sample this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
// detecting here is scroll called by some script( $.scrollTo('#somediv') for sample ) or by mousewheel
});
```

Comment: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos might he;lp look for event `mousewheel`, hope it fits your need!

Comment: to tats_innit: it's not necessarily be a scroll event, scroll event is only for sample

Comment: @underfined it's always be scroll))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use an additional parameter and use it in my dynamic calls to that function.

```
$('.item').click(function(event,explicit) {
    if (explicit) console.log("I'm called explicitly!");
})
```

can be triggered like `$('.item').trigger('click',true)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if(!e.isTrigger) {
        // mouse wheel
        console.log('wheeeeeel');
    }
});
```

[**demo using mouse wheel event**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7bp9/)

[**demo using click event**](http://jsfiddle.net/SZF8T/)

Comment: when i use $.scrollTo( target ), console also prints 'wheeeeel'

Comment: Are you using IE? change `console.log` to `alert('texthere');`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vap6f/ i need when a call $.scrollTo('#someid') 'wheeel' must not display, when i sroll by mouse 'wheeel' is displaing